# How to add Vue component in other application separately

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, devops, software-design

I'm gonna develop some Component base on Vue . the client wants me to provide and structure to use this component separately in other projects.(these project either implement by Vue or not)
the component should be used lonely or customize by some props that I expose in documentation **(like Telerik Ui package)**
how should I develop the components and how to use clients in their project?

Comment: I do not think your client will be able to use a Vue component in non-Vue application. But you can provide him a "widget" instead of component - with the help of https://vuidget.danajanoskova.sk/

Comment: Thanks for responding
this is good and we could add our component in every project independently. just a question is :with this structure we have to create a project for each components that we want. is that Right?

Comment: My point was - if you want to combine your components in a library (like Vuetify, Quasar, or many other libraries) then you should be aware that it will be very difficult to use these components in a non-Vue application. So my suggestion to you and your client is that you build complete Vue application(s) with routes and Vuex, and then allow the embedding of such "widgets" into any other website, no matter if it is SPA (e.g. React-based) or a static website. IF your client still needs components rather than widgets - you'd better develop them in pure vanilla JavaScript.